# text file to arraylist javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a txt file on `mydomain.net/file.txt`.How can I read this into an array `filecontent` where each new line is a element and ignore lines containing `//`? .

JavaScript

```
    var filecontent=[];
    function txtToArray(link){
    //code here
    }
    txtToArray("mydomain.net/file.txt");
document.write(filecontent);
```

mydomain.net/file.txt

```
//file.txt
    aaa
    aa1
    aa2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in the browser, you'll have to [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the file, parse the response as text, [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the text into an array of lines, and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array for lines that do not start with `//`, then write the filtered array:

```js
function filterAndWrite(text) {
    const arrayOfLines = text.split('\n');
    const startsWithDoubleSlash = new RegExp('^//');
    const filteredLines = arrayOfLines.filter((line) => !line.match(startsWithDoubleSlash));
    document.write(filteredLines);
}

function writeToDocument(link) {
    fetch(link)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then(filterAndWrite);
}

writeToDocument('mydomain.net/file.txt');
```